# I have this code that is currently using web browser. How can I convert this to webclient?

Tags: vb.net, webclient

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As      System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
For Each Image As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Images
    If Image.GetAttribute("src").Contains("captcha") Then
        Dim Web As New Net.WebClient
        PictureBox1.Image = New Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(Web.DownloadData(Image.GetAttribute("src"))))
    End If
Next 
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm trying to find a way to convert this over to webclient. Thanks

Comment: You have posted an event handler for a `WebBrowser` - without knowing what else is done with the control, it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient

Dim url As String = "yourPageURL"
Dim htmlByte() As Byte = webClient.DownloadData(url)

Dim htmlString As String
htmlString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(htmlByte)

' Generally using Regexes for Parsing HTML is not a good idea, this is just an example, you would use something like HTMLAgilityPack for parsing.

' A quick and dirty hack that just make it work when html is minified
htmlString = htmlString.Replace("<", System.Environment.NewLine + "<");

Dim matches As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection
Dim pattern As String = "<img.*?src\s*=\s*[""'](?<src>[^""']+)[""'].*?>"
matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(htmlString, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

For Each match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In matches
    If (Not match.Groups.Item("src").ToString().ToLower().Contains("captcha")) Then Continue For

    PictureBox1.Image = New Drawing.Bitmap(New System.IO.MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(match.Groups.Item("src").ToString())))
Next
```

Comment: Cool thanks Fardjad..I will play around with this for a while to get it to work but right it's giving me slew of a errors to sort out. But nothing I can't work through.

Comment: @ChrisWheelous To be honest, this code is not tested (but I'm sure that the Regex part is correct :D). I'm a `C#` guy, many errors might be found in the code above. If you made it work, just edit the answer and I will accept the edit (or paste the code in pastebin.com and share the link, so I can make the answer correct.)

Comment: Thanks ago for the help. I will continue to sift through the code but if you have it in C# then you can paste the working code as well and I can use that also. But here is the pastebin link   http://pastebin.com/Q8Zf8Fav

Comment: @ChrisWheelous I can see no differences between the code in paste bin.com and mine, so it that the working version?

Comment: oh sorry...I misread the answer..I thought you said you would make the answer correct if I posted it in pastebin....to me that meant you would correct the issues...no worries..I will work on it here and get it working..then I will post the working code on here.

Comment: Okay so I have found the way to get the images by src for a website but I am not getting what I need. I need to grab this particular img src but it's giving me everything else.  <div id="recaptcha_image" class="width: 300px; height: 57px;" style="width: 300px; height: 57px;">
<img width="300" height="57" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VuvlvMA4JvVIQvDR4C_iDbOTwOF5FUIRPGkkSImDRYAD6sY2L0IxyJSpSP1WGjWqr0MQ-dmjkiIgevFY2gkMpNWi1cQbtgUZB5QaYr_vIHv6xFzG9ydFbBWs4xiEhWoxHEFUYHZj6CCh4obyZSOd2La0nozLZw" style="display:block;">
</div>

Comment: @ChrisWheelous I installed `VB.NET` and fixed the code the problem was `match.Groups("src")` that should be changed to `match.Groups.Item("src")` Updated the answer.